# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting in python

Tags: python, typeerror

Any idea why I get this errror-message:

```
    editResponsHtml """ % (person, pId)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting?
```

Code:

```
def editRespons(form):
   global FAMILYTREE

   FAMILYTREE.editPerson(int(form.getvalue("id").decode('latin-1')), form.getvalue("firstName").decode('latin-1'), form.getvalue("lastName").decode('latin-1'), form.getvalue("bYear").decode('latin-1'), form.getvalue("dYear").decode('latin-1'), form.getvalue("mom").decode('latin-1'), form.getvalue("dad").decode('latin-1'))
   person = FAMILYTREE.getPerson(form.getvalue("id"))

   return editResponsHtml(person, person.fid)


def editResponsHtml(person, pId):
   return u"""<p>%s sparades!</p>
   """ % (person, pId)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in two values to format with, but specify only *one* slot.

The slot count and number of parameters must match. Either add a slot for `pId` or remove it from the tuple:

```
def editResponsHtml(person, pId):
   return u"""<p>%s %s sparades!</p>
   """ % (person, pId)

def editResponsHtml(person, pId):
   return u"""<p>%s sparades!</p>
   """ % (person,)
```

Alternatively, use named slots and a dictionary:

```
def editResponsHtml(person, pId):
   return u"""<p>%(person)s sparades!</p>
   """ % {'person': person, 'pId': pId}
```

which won't complain about unused keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
return u"""<p>%s sparades!</p>
```

""" % (person, pId)

You have one format specifier (`%s`) but two values: `person` and `pId`, you do not have a specifier, like `%d` for `pId`.